# Add "Updates Available" in custom MOTD

Tags: command-line, scripts, motd

I have been tweaking my MOTD using [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-welcome-message-motd-on-ubuntu-18-04-server) tutorial.

I used the same layout as the one in the tutorial shown here:

```
echo "GENERAL SYSTEM INFORMATION"
/usr/bin/screenfetch
echo
echo "SYSTEM DISK USAGE"
export TERM=xterm; inxi -D
echo
echo "CURRENT WEATHER FORECAST"
# Show weather information. Change the city name to fit your location
ansiweather -l MYSTATE,USA -u imperial
```

My question is, since I disabled the dynamic MOTD and used my own, is there a way I can enable the "90-updates-available" section in the dynamic MOTD so I can see when there are upgrades available?

I can give any additional information upon request.

Comment: There is no real magic in that section. You can easily get the same sort of output using `apt list --upgradeable`. However, that information is often stale regardless of method. Your system does not run an apt update at startup (unless you have added one), and MOTD does not update the numbers after unattended-upgrade runs.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you for the speedy response. What would you suggest I do to add something like this to my MOTD? Would I simply just add it to the bash script that I am currently using? Or is this only offered using the dynamic MOTD?

Comment: I find `unattended-upgrades` does a good job at patching important updates and regularly keeping the local apt list up to date. If you log in and there are packages available for update you should get a message under the MOTD notifying you that you have X number of updates available, and X number are security updates. You shouldn't need to do anything - this is the default behavior of Ubuntu, at least it is in 20.04 (you didn't specify which release)